# Generate dynamic custom intervals

Tags: sql-server-2014

I am working on a project that requires reports that can dynamically group the source data on non-standard user defined intervals such as Production Shifts within a specified start and end range. Example user may want to see production information group by shift for the last two days. 
I created a table called ‘IntervalConfiguration’ that stores the configuration information required to create the grouping intervals with data as follow:

```
IntervalType                SubIntervalType     IntervalDuration     IntervalDurationUnits  IntervalStartReferenceTime IntervalRepeatDuration IntervalRepeatDurationUnits
-------------------------   ------------------- -------------------- ---------------------  -------------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------------
Production Day              ProductionDay       1                    Days                   2013-01-07 07:00:00.000    1                      Days
Production Month            ProductionMonth     1                    Months                 2013-01-01 07:00:00.000    1                      Months
Production Week             ProductionWeek      1                    Weeks                  2013-01-07 08:45:00.000    1                      Weeks
Production Year             ProductionYear      1                    Years                  2013-01-01 08:45:00.000    1                      Years
Site A - Production Shift   Day                 12                   Hours                  2013-01-06 07:00:00.000    24                     Hours
Site A - Production Shift   Night               12                   Hours                  2013-01-06 19:00:00.000    24                     Hours
Site B - Production Shift   Day                 12                   Hours                  2013-01-06 06:45:00.000    24                     Hours
Site B - Production Shift   Night               12                   Hours                  2013-01-06 18:45:00.000    24                     Hours
```

If a user selects ‘Site A - Production Shift’ as the grouping interval on the report and a start date of '01/01/2018' and end date of '01/05/2018' then the report has to create grouping intervals for day shifts where day shifts start at 7AM and ends at 7PM and night shift where night shift start at 7PM and ends at 7AM the next day. 
Also, only grouping intervals completely contained within the start and end date should be returned. Below is an example of expected grouping intervals for the scenario described.

```
SubIntervalType     IntervalStart            IntervalEnd             
----------------    -----------------------  ----------------------- 
Day                 2018-01-01 07:00:00.000  2018-01-01 19:00:00.000 
Night               2018-01-01 19:00:00.000  2018-01-02 07:00:00.000 
Day                 2018-01-02 07:00:00.000  2018-01-02 19:00:00.000 
Night               2018-01-02 19:00:00.000  2018-01-03 07:00:00.000 
Day                 2018-01-03 07:00:00.000  2018-01-03 19:00:00.000 
Night               2018-01-03 19:00:00.000  2018-01-04 07:00:00.000 
Day                 2018-01-04 07:00:00.000  2018-01-04 19:00:00.000
```

If user selects Production Month as the grouping interval with a start date of '01/01/2018' and end date of '01/01/2019' then the report should generate the following grouping intervals.

```
SubIntervalType     IntervalStart           IntervalEnd            
-----------------   ----------------------- -----------------------
ProductionMonth     2018-01-01 07:00:00.000 2018-02-01 07:00:00.000
ProductionMonth     2018-02-01 07:00:00.000 2018-03-01 07:00:00.000
ProductionMonth     2018-03-01 07:00:00.000 2018-04-01 07:00:00.000
ProductionMonth     2018-04-01 07:00:00.000 2018-05-01 07:00:00.000
ProductionMonth     2018-05-01 07:00:00.000 2018-06-01 07:00:00.000
ProductionMonth     2018-06-01 07:00:00.000 2018-07-01 07:00:00.000
ProductionMonth     2018-07-01 07:00:00.000 2018-08-01 07:00:00.000
ProductionMonth     2018-08-01 07:00:00.000 2018-09-01 07:00:00.000
ProductionMonth     2018-09-01 07:00:00.000 2018-10-01 07:00:00.000
ProductionMonth     2018-10-01 07:00:00.000 2018-11-01 07:00:00.000
ProductionMonth     2018-11-01 07:00:00.000 2018-12-01 07:00:00.000
```

I have started building the following table valued function to dynamically create the desired grouping intervals.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetIntervals]
(
    @dateRangeStart datetime,
    @dateRangeEnd   datetime,
    @groupByInterval    NVARCHAR(200)
)
RETURNS @Intervals TABLE (
    IntervalType            NVARCHAR(100)
    ,SubIntervalType        NVARCHAR(100)
    ,IntervalStart          DATETIME
    ,IntervalEnd                DATETIME
    ,IntervalDurationSeconds    FLOAT
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @activeIntervalDateTime DATETIME = DATEADD(millisecond, 3, @dateRangeStart);
    DECLARE @intervalStartTime DATETIME = DATEADD(s, 1, @dateRangeStart);
    DECLARE @intervalEndTime DATETIME = DATEADD(s, 1, @dateRangeStart);
    DECLARE @intervalDurationSeconds FLOAT;
    DECLARE @intervalName NVARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE @subIntervalType NVARCHAR(100);

    WHILE @intervalStartTime <= @dateRangeEnd
    BEGIN

        SELECT   TOP 1
                 @intervalName = IntervalType ,@subIntervalType = SubIntervalType , @intervalStartTime = IntervalStart, @intervalEndTime = IntervalEnd
        FROM    (SELECT  IntervalType, SubIntervalType, IntervalDuration, IntervalDurationUnits,
                            IntervalRepeatDuration, IntervalRepeatDurationUnits,
                            CASE IntervalRepeatDurationUnits
                             WHEN 'Hours' THEN (DateAdd(HH, (DateDiff(HH, IntervalStartReferenceTime, ActiveTimeNormalized ) / IntervalRepeatDuration) * IntervalRepeatDuration,  IntervalStartReferenceTime))
                             WHEN 'Days' THEN (DateAdd(D, (DateDiff(D, IntervalStartReferenceTime, ActiveTimeNormalized ) / IntervalRepeatDuration) * IntervalRepeatDuration,  IntervalStartReferenceTime))
                             WHEN 'Months'THEN (DateAdd(MM, (DateDiff(MM, IntervalStartReferenceTime, ActiveTimeNormalized ) / IntervalRepeatDuration) * IntervalRepeatDuration,  IntervalStartReferenceTime))
                             END AS IntervalStart,
                            CASE IntervalRepeatDurationUnits
                             WHEN 'Hours' THEN (DateAdd(HH, IntervalDuration, DateAdd(HH, (DateDiff(HH, IntervalStartReferenceTime, ActiveTimeNormalized ) / IntervalRepeatDuration) * IntervalRepeatDuration,  IntervalStartReferenceTime)))
                             WHEN 'Days' THEN 
                                CASE IntervalDurationUnits
                                WHEN 'Hours' THEN (DateAdd(HH, IntervalDuration, DateAdd(D, (DateDiff(D, IntervalStartReferenceTime, ActiveTimeNormalized ) / IntervalRepeatDuration) * IntervalRepeatDuration,  IntervalStartReferenceTime)))
                                WHEN 'Days' THEN (DateAdd(D, IntervalDuration, DateAdd(D, (DateDiff(D, IntervalStartReferenceTime, ActiveTimeNormalized ) / IntervalRepeatDuration) * IntervalRepeatDuration,  IntervalStartReferenceTime)))
                                END
                             WHEN 'Months'THEN 
                                CASE IntervalDurationUnits
                                WHEN 'Hours' THEN (DateAdd(HH, IntervalDuration, DateAdd(MM, (DateDiff(MM, IntervalStartReferenceTime, ActiveTimeNormalized ) / IntervalRepeatDuration) * IntervalRepeatDuration,  IntervalStartReferenceTime)))
                                WHEN 'Days' THEN (DateAdd(D, IntervalDuration, DateAdd(MM, (DateDiff(MM, IntervalStartReferenceTime, ActiveTimeNormalized ) / IntervalRepeatDuration) * IntervalRepeatDuration,  IntervalStartReferenceTime)))
                                WHEN 'Months' THEN (DateAdd(MM, IntervalDuration, DateAdd(MM, (DateDiff(MM, IntervalStartReferenceTime, ActiveTimeNormalized ) / IntervalRepeatDuration) * IntervalRepeatDuration,  IntervalStartReferenceTime)))
                                END
                             END AS IntervalEnd
                            ,IntervalStartReferenceTime
                FROM    (
                            SELECT   IntervalType, SubIntervalType, IntervalDuration, IntervalDurationUnits, IntervalRepeatDuration, IntervalRepeatDurationUnits, IntervalStartReferenceTime,
                                     CASE IntervalRepeatDurationUnits
                                     WHEN 'Hours' THEN DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1*(DATEPART(MILLISECOND, IntervalStartReferenceTime) + 3), DATEADD(SECOND, -1*DATEPART(SECOND, IntervalStartReferenceTime), DATEADD(MINUTE, -1*DATEPART(MINUTE, IntervalStartReferenceTime), @activeIntervalDateTime)))
                                     WHEN 'Days' THEN DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1*(DATEPART(MILLISECOND, IntervalStartReferenceTime) + 3), DATEADD(SECOND, -1*DATEPART(SECOND, IntervalStartReferenceTime), DATEADD(MINUTE, -1*DATEPART(MINUTE, IntervalStartReferenceTime), DATEADD(HOUR, -1*DATEPART(HOUR, IntervalStartReferenceTime), @activeIntervalDateTime))))
                                     WHEN 'Months' THEN DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1*(DATEPART(MILLISECOND, IntervalStartReferenceTime) + 3), DATEADD(SECOND, -1*DATEPART(SECOND, IntervalStartReferenceTime), DATEADD(MINUTE, -1*DATEPART(MINUTE, IntervalStartReferenceTime), DATEADD(HOUR, -1*DATEPART(HOUR, IntervalStartReferenceTime), DATEADD(DAY, -1*(DATEPART(DAY, IntervalStartReferenceTime) - 1), @activeIntervalDateTime)))))
                                     END AS ActiveTimeNormalized
                            FROM    dbo.IntervalConfiguration               
                        ) norm
                WHERE   IntervalType = @groupByInterval) interval
        WHERE   (@activeIntervalDateTime > IntervalStart) and (@activeIntervalDateTime <= IntervalEnd)
        ORDER BY IntervalStartReferenceTime DESC


        SET @intervalDurationSeconds = DATEDIFF(SECOND, @intervalStartTime, @intervalEndTime);

        IF @intervalStartTime >= @dateRangeStart AND @intervalEndTime <= @dateRangeEnd 
        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO @Intervals( 
                                         IntervalType
                                         ,SubIntervalType           
                                        ,IntervalStart          
                                        ,IntervalEnd            
                                        ,IntervalDurationSeconds                                    
                                      )
            VALUES(
                     @intervalName
                    ,@subIntervalType
                    ,@intervalStartTime
                    ,@intervalEndTime
                    ,@intervalDurationSeconds
                  )

        END

        SET @activeIntervalDateTime = DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 3, @intervalEndTime);

    END

    RETURN;
END
```

This function however is getting increasingly complex and hard to debug also I would like to eliminate the need to use While loops within the function. My question is this, is there a simpler way to achieve my requirements and is it possible to eliminate the need for a while loop?

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have SSRS or another reporting tool? It seems like you are trying to reinvent that wheel, perhaps because you don't have those tools but I can see it only growing more complex.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is reporting tool developed within our organization, it only allows for the most basic time-based aggregation such as hourly, daily etc. but no custom defined intervals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely simplify the query and eliminate the while loop through the use of a tally table as demonstrated below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetIntervals]
(   
    @startRange datetime,
    @endRange   datetime,
    @groupByPeriod  NVARCHAR(200)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    WITH Tally (N) AS
    (
        SELECT 0 UNION ALL
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
        FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n)               -- 10 rows
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n)         -- 100 rows
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(n)         -- 1,000 rows
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) d(n)         -- 10,000 rows
        --CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) e(n)       -- 100,000 rows
        --CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) f(n)       -- 1,000,000 rows
    ), 
    Intervals
    AS
    (
        SELECT       I.IntervalType
                    ,I.SubIntervalType
                    ,I.IntervalDuration
                    ,I.IntervalDurationUnits
                    ,I.IntervalStartReferenceTime
                    ,I.IntervalRepeatDuration
                    ,I.IntervalRepeatDurationUnits
                    ,(
                        CASE 
                            WHEN I.IntervalRepeatDurationUnits = 'Years' AND N < 500 THEN DATEADD(YEAR, ((DATEDIFF(YEAR, I.IntervalStartReferenceTime, @startRange) / I.IntervalRepeatDuration) + N) * I.IntervalRepeatDuration ,I.IntervalStartReferenceTime) 
                            WHEN I.IntervalRepeatDurationUnits = 'Months' AND N < 6000 THEN DATEADD(MONTH, ((DATEDIFF(MONTH, I.IntervalStartReferenceTime, @startRange) / I.IntervalRepeatDuration) + N) * I.IntervalRepeatDuration ,I.IntervalStartReferenceTime)
                            WHEN I.IntervalRepeatDurationUnits = 'Weeks' AND N < 24000 THEN DATEADD(WEEK, ((DATEDIFF(WEEK, I.IntervalStartReferenceTime, @startRange) / I.IntervalRepeatDuration) + N) * I.IntervalRepeatDuration ,I.IntervalStartReferenceTime)
                            WHEN I.IntervalRepeatDurationUnits = 'Days' THEN DATEADD(DAY, ((DATEDIFF(DAY, I.IntervalStartReferenceTime, @startRange) / I.IntervalRepeatDuration)  + N) * I.IntervalRepeatDuration ,I.IntervalStartReferenceTime)
                            WHEN I.IntervalRepeatDurationUnits = 'Hours' THEN DATEADD(HOUR, ((DATEDIFF(HOUR, I.IntervalStartReferenceTime, @startRange) / I.IntervalRepeatDuration) + N) * I.IntervalRepeatDuration ,I.IntervalStartReferenceTime)
                        END 
                     ) AS IntervalStart
                     ,Tally.N
        FROM        IntervalConfiguration I
        CROSS JOIN  Tally
        WHERE       (I.IntervalType = @groupByPeriod) 
                        AND
                     (
                        N BETWEEN 0 AND (
                            CASE I.IntervalRepeatDurationUnits
                                WHEN 'Years' THEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, @startRange, @endRange) / I.IntervalRepeatDuration 
                                WHEN 'Months' THEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, @startRange, @endRange) / I.IntervalRepeatDuration  
                                WHEN 'Weeks' THEN DATEDIFF(WEEK, @startRange, @endRange) / I.IntervalRepeatDuration 
                                WHEN 'Days' THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, @startRange, @endRange) / I.IntervalRepeatDuration 
                                WHEN 'Hours' THEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, @startRange, @endRange) / I.IntervalRepeatDuration 
                            END)
                    )
    )
    SELECT       TOP 100 PERCENT
                 I.IntervalType
                ,I.SubIntervalType
                ,I.IntervalDuration
                ,I.IntervalDurationUnits
                ,I.IntervalStartReferenceTime
                ,I.IntervalRepeatDuration
                ,I.IntervalRepeatDurationUnits
                ,I.IntervalStart
                ,(
                    CASE I.IntervalDurationUnits
                        WHEN 'Years' THEN DATEADD(YEAR, I.IntervalDuration, I.IntervalStart)
                        WHEN 'Months' THEN DATEADD(MONTH, I.IntervalDuration, I.IntervalStart)
                        WHEN 'Weeks' THEN DATEADD(WEEK,  I.IntervalDuration, I.IntervalStart)
                        WHEN 'Days' THEN DATEADD(DAY, I.IntervalDuration, I.IntervalStart)
                        WHEN 'Hours' THEN DATEADD(HOUR, I.IntervalDuration, I.IntervalStart)
                    END 
                 ) AS IntervalEnd
                 ,N
    FROM        Intervals I
    WHERE       I.IntervalStart >= @startRange 
                AND 
                (
                    CASE I.IntervalDurationUnits
                        WHEN 'Years' THEN DATEADD(YEAR, I.IntervalDuration, I.IntervalStart)
                        WHEN 'Months' THEN DATEADD(MONTH, I.IntervalDuration, I.IntervalStart)
                        WHEN 'Weeks' THEN DATEADD(WEEK,  I.IntervalDuration, I.IntervalStart)
                        WHEN 'Days' THEN DATEADD(DAY, I.IntervalDuration, I.IntervalStart)
                        WHEN 'Hours' THEN DATEADD(HOUR, I.IntervalDuration, I.IntervalStart)
                    END 
                 ) <= @endRange
    ORDER BY    I.IntervalStart
)
```

Comment: I will try your example and see how it goes. I think I get the general idea of your query but I am not sure what the N < 500 check is for in the case statement calculating IntervalStart

Comment: @MathewT the check is to prevent an overflow when the DateAdd function is called. Depending on how SQL Server optimizes the query it may execute the DateAdd for all possible rows generated from the tally table (100,000 rows) despite the where clause that is suppose the limit the number of rows from the tally table.